# How to get NSManagedObjectId and retrieve data

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, uitableview

I have a TableViewController called HomeTableViewController loaded with data from a Core Data array. I attempted to get the object Id from the selected cell like so:

```
//Fetch Entity

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"OwedMoney"];

//Create an array that stores the contents of that entity

youOweArray = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

//Create managedObjectId

NSManagedObject *YouOweData  = [youOweArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSManagedObjectID *moID = [YouOweData objectID];

//Successfully got the managedObjectId

NSLog(@"This is the id %@", moID);
```

I was able to get the managedObjectId. But here comes the difficult part. Now I want to iterate through my array and get all the objects. Then I want to get the object that equals to the selected cell and access it's boolean value of "Paid". I did THAT like so:

```
 BOOL Found =  NO;
OwedMoney *OwedObject;
NSManagedObjectID *OwedId = [OwedObject objectID];

for (OwedMoney *OwedObject in youOweArray)
{

    NSLog(@"%@", OwedObject);
    if (OwedId == moID)
    {
        Found = YES;
        break;
    }

}

if (Found == YES)
{

BOOL isPaid = YES;
OwedMoney *Object = OwedObject;
Object.paid = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isPaid];

NSLog(@"Is it paid: %@",Object.paid? @"Yes":@"No");
}
```

Although when I run the application, Found is never equal to YES. This means my object Id's aren't matching up. I'd like to know how of a way to find the selected table view cell, grab the NSManagedObjectId from it, and then access it's attributes.

All help is appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping through the array, but never actually changing the OwedId to what item you're looking at in the array. This should work:

```
BOOL Found =  NO;
OwedMoney *Object;


for (OwedMoney *OwedObject in youOweArray)
{
    NSManagedObjectID *OwedId = [OwedObject objectID];

    NSLog(@"%@", OwedObject);
    if (OwedId == moID)
    {
        Found = YES;
        Object = OwedObject;
        break;
    }

}

if (Found)
{

    BOOL isPaid = Found;
    Object.paid = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isPaid];

    NSLog(@"Is it paid: %@",Object.paid.boolValue? @"Yes":@"No");
}
```

Comment: I implemented this and Paid is still returning no

Comment: Ah nevermind,  minor bug on my part, it's returning Yes!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on line 9.

```
if(OweID == moID)
```

Probably the ID object (not the ID information itself) of the managed object changed. Using == compares only the references. Try to use

```
if([OweID isEqual::moID])
```

Thomas